# Batch: Read out number, iterate and write back

Tags: file, batch-file

I want a text file with just a number that is getting iterated every time i use the batch file. I tried this so far but its not working...

```
set laufende_nr=0
if not exist echo %laufende_nr% > %def_log_dir%\laufende_nr.tmp
for /L %%i in (%def_log_dir%\laufende_nr.tmp) set laufende_nr=%%i
echo %laufende_nr%
set /a laufende_nr+=laufende_nr
echo %laufende_nr_neu% > %def_log_dir%\laufende_nr.tmp
```

Comment: You should consider opening up a cmd prompt and reading the help for the FOR command. Type for /?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's some quick example code for you to study:

```bat
Set "laufende_nr="
If Exist "%def_log_dir%\laufende_nr.tmp" (
    Set/P "laufende_nr="<"%def_log_dir%\laufende_nr.tmp"
)
If Not Defined laufende_nr Set "laufende_nr=0"
Echo %laufende_nr%
Set/A laufende_nr+=1
(Echo %laufende_nr%)>"%def_log_dir%\laufende_nr.tmp"
```

Enter `Set/?`, `If/?` & `Echo/?` as necessary for respective information.

***Edit***
If you have a relative directory named `Set` which contains an executable file named either `A` or `P`, then you would be best advised to change `Set/A` to `Set /A` and/or change `Set/P` to `Set /P` as necessary.

Comment: __Note:__ The right command line syntax is __command__ *space* __argument__ *space* __argument__ ... The command line `Set/A laufende_nr+=1` with no space between command `Set` and argument `/A` can result in executing a file with name `a` with a file extension as specified in environment variable `PATHEXT` in subdirectory `set` with first and only argument `laufende_nr+=1`. The same possible issue exists here with `Set/P "laufende_nr="` where the actually needed space between command and argument is also missing. For help on commands run `command /?` in a command prompt window like `set /?`.

Comment: @Mofi, one could of course, as given in my answer, just run `command/?`, _(without a space)_, because **`?`** is not allowed Windows file/directory naming.

Comment: Yes, one __could__ run `command/?` as this always works as expected because `?` is not allowed in a file/directory name and error handling of Windows command interpreter finds out that `command` is the __command__ and `/?` is the __argument__. But nobody __should__ run `command/?`, but use always correct syntax `command /?`. Learning the right syntax is essential for beginners on command line. Executables ported from Unix require often `-?` or `-h` or `--help` as argument to get displayed the help. `ping-?` does not work, but `ping -?` and also `ping /?` (and `ping/?` by cmd error correction).